# link error while using iconv lib with dcmtk

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I built dcmtk with iconv.lib and used that lib in to my application by including t in additional dependancies. while biulding that got a link error

> 1>ofstd.lib(ofchrenc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) int _libiconv_version"
>   (_*imp*?_libiconv_version@@3HA)

how to resolve this error can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you add it to Linker->Input?

Answer (score 0):

In iconv.h, adding declaration inside extern "C" helps

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
extern LIBICONV_DLL_EXPORTED int _libiconv_version;
...
}
```